# How to print the minor index of a Panel?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Here is my panel:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(4))
pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(4))

data = {'Item1' : pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(4,3)), 
        'Item2' : pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(4,3))}

p = pd.Panel(data)
print p
```

The result looks as follow:

```
               Item1    Item2
major   minor       
0       0   -0.341730   0.320261
        1   -0.479931   0.310665
        2   -0.442754   -1.254306
1       0   -2.422451   -0.598516
        1   -1.558052   -0.336209
        2   -0.535727   -0.119105
2       0   0.181917    2.148452
        1   0.357893    -0.664193
        2   0.878866    0.985667
3       0   -0.752161   1.307015
        1   0.915825    -0.665634
        2   -1.190466   0.446089
```

I wonder how to print out the name of the minor index, though they are just numbers?

Comment: are you looking for this `p.minor_axis`?

Comment: seems not correct. The result is RangeIndex(start=0, stop=3, step=1)